# Как правильней обрабатывать POST запросы в Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Только начинаю изучать node.js.

Делаю страницу авторизации пользователя. При заполнении форм, отправляю его запрос к страницам по типу

```
router.post('/register', 
 userController.validateRegister,
 userController.register,
 authController.login
)
router.post('/login', authController.login);
```

Вопрос. Можно ли реализовать запросы к одной и той же странице, и как мне на серверной стороне проверять, с каким я запросом работаю?

1. В мидлвар проверять значения скрытого инпута/названия формы, и, в случае `register` идти по одному пути, иначе другим?
2. Или же вариант, который я сейчас использую есть наиболее оптимальным методом использования POST запросов?